# Unity: render black colors gray

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

How can I make Unity render black colors gray? It can be a shader, shadergraph, SRP or anything but a Runtime script.

I know Post Processing cannot change black colors.

Comment: where exactly do you want to replace the color, the final image?

Comment: On meshes. Actually, I have some 3D Objects in my scene which they have some black parts, that means material's color on their MeshRenderer components are kind of black. I want to make them grey.

Comment: please provide a picture of the object and the inspector?

Comment: I think there is no need for photo. It is very simple. Imagine a cube with black material on it. Make Unity render it grey in GameView without touching the material color on the cube.

Comment: I assume what you want is a post processing effect?

Comment: Three Problems with PP:
1. It is affecting the other colors as well.
2. Is it possible to change black color which is by definition is absent of any color value to another color?
3. It is a little bit expensive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188486/discussion-between-mohsenne-and-0xbfe1a8).

Answer (score 0):

use color grading from the postprocessing stack

*EDIT:* 
Because Color Grading over PostProcessingStack isn't a valid solution this could work:

Shader that changes if _Color is Black(0,0,0,Alpha)

```
Shader "Custom/Grey"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _GreyColor ("Grey Color", Color) = (0.3,0.3,0.3,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _MainCol;
        fixed4 _GreyColor;


        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
        {
            if(_Color.r == 0 && _Color.g == 0 && _Color.b == 0){
                _MainCol = _GreyColor;
            }else{
                _MainCol = _Color;
            }
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _MainCol;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, apparently it is not possible. You can not change black colors with Color Grading in PP stack. If you could do it, let me know.

Comment: have a look for tonemapping, this could possably work

Comment: By ToneMapping, you mean ColorGrading? I tried. It works on every color except Black.

Comment: can you post an image of a model?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, imagine two cubes, one with black color and another one with orange. The challenge is to make the black cube look grey without touching the orange cube color.

Comment: well you could get all materials, and check for their colors if it’s a solid black(0,0,0,1) you could access those materials and set them to grey

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, anything except a runtime script. It is not efficient for me. Imagine, I have two million black cubes, each one has 3 layers of children. 
The only solution for me is to make Unity render black color, gray.

Comment: could you do an editor script and dragndrop all materials into a list?(there’s a filter browser for materials)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188628/discussion-between-mohsenne-and-dan-wipf).